# acos function in Sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, trigonometry

I have a question about SQLite queries.
I need to execute a sqlite query like this:

```
SELECT
    id, (
      6371 * acos (
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 30
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

But I obtain an error because Sqlite not support functions like `acos`.
Is there a way to execute my query in Sqlite?
I need to use this on iOS.
Any practical suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Maybe you could use extension-functions.c from the [contributed files](http://www.sqlite.org/contrib)

Comment: I think you basically want too much.  Select the rows that have lat/lng values within min/max bounds and then read the selected rows and do the computation on the extracted values.  It will likely be faster than the above, if you could even make the above work.

Comment: BTW, the `HAVING` clause should only be used in conjunction with a `GROUP BY` clause. If you are not using `GROUP BY`, then just use a `WHERE` clause instead of `HAVING`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement your own functions in SQLite. For example, write a SQLite C function wrapper for `acos`:

```
void sqlite_acos(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    int dataType = sqlite3_value_numeric_type(argv[0]);

    if (dataType == SQLITE_INTEGER || dataType == SQLITE_FLOAT) {
        double value = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]);
        sqlite3_result_double(context, acos(value));
    } else {
        sqlite3_result_null(context);
    }
}
```

You can repeat this process for each of these trigonometric functions you need.

Then call `sqlite3_create_function` to map this C function to a SQL expression:

```
- (BOOL)createFunctions:(sqlite3 *)db
{
    int rc;

    if ((rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "acos", 1, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, sqlite_acos, NULL, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_create_function acos error: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), rc);
    }

    // repeat this for all of the other functions you define

    return rc;
}
```

---

Frankly, rather than writing these individual trigonometric functions, I'd write one that does the higher-level distance calculation. That would be a little more efficient. That might look something like:

```
double radians(double degrees)
{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
}

void sqlite_distance(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    double values[4];

    // get the double values for the four arguments

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int dataType = sqlite3_value_numeric_type(argv[i]);

        if (dataType == SQLITE_INTEGER || dataType == SQLITE_FLOAT) {
            values[i] = sqlite3_value_double(argv[i]);
        } else {
            sqlite3_result_null(context);
            return;
        }
    }

    // let's give those values meaningful variable names

    double lat  = radians(values[0]);
    double lng  = radians(values[1]);
    double lat2 = radians(values[2]);
    double lng2 = radians(values[3]);

    // calculate the distance

    double result = 6371.0 * acos(cos(lat2) * cos(lat) * cos(lng - lng2) + sin(lat2) * sin(lat));

    sqlite3_result_double(context, result);
}
```

And you'd then define a `distance` function in SQLite, like so:

```
int rc;

if ((rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "distance", 4, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, sqlite_distance, NULL, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_create_function distance error: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), rc);
}
```

So, you open the database, call `sqlite3_create_function` for this `distance` function, and then you can write SQL that uses this new `distance` function:

```
const char *sql = "SELECT "
                    "id, distance(lat, lng, 65.3234, 78.3232) AS distance "
                    "FROM markers "
                    "WHERE distance < 30 "
                    "ORDER BY distance";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    sqlite3_int64 rowid = sqlite3_column_int64(statement, 0);
    double distance = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);
    NSLog(@"%lld %f", rowid, distance);
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

That `distance` function is valid until you close the database, so make sure to call `sqlite3_create_function` every time you open the database.

Comment: thanks..How can I use your distance function in my sql query?Sorry but I'm new abut this..

Comment: @Safari I've added demonstration of how you'd then use that `distance` function.