# Php Sqlite acos function

Tags: php, laravel, location, query-builder

In `Laravel` I've got a query builder method for ordering items based on 
the users location with `long` and `latitude`.

It looks like this:

```
public function location($location)
{
    $location = explode(',', $location);

    $lat = $location[0];
    $long = $location[1];

    return $this->builder->select(\DB::raw(sprintf('(
              6371 * acos (
              cos ( radians(%s) )
              * cos( radians( lat ) )
              * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(%s) )
              + sin ( radians(%s) )
              * sin( radians( lat ) )
            )
        ) AS distance', $lat, $long, $lat)))
        ->orderBy('distance');
}
```

The problem is that I use a sqlite database. And `acos` is not supported. How could I get this to work with sqlite?

Already saw this but this is not for php I guess?

[acos function in Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612538/acos-function-in-sqlite)